# How to check if 3 nodes in a row are identical C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have a linkedList, I wanted to check if there are 3 nodes in a row that have the same data/value, if so i want to remove them from the list.

ex. 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7, 5; // here from index 3-5 have same value, then the new list will be
**new list:** 1, 2, 3, 7, 5

this is my code, I just got confused on how to keep track of the previous 2 values so I can campare them with the node that the current pointer pointing to.

//assume the rest of my code works fine

```
void Remove_ThreeDuplicates()
{
    Node *current= head;
    Node *prev = current;
    Node *prev_prev = prev;

    //keep track of identical found
    int i = 0;

    while(current->next != NULL)
   {
       prev_prev =head_ptr;
       prev = prev_prev->Next;
       current = prev->Next;


      //checks if nodes are identical
       if(prev_prev->data == prev->data && prev->data == current->data)
       {
         //remove the 3 identical nodes
         prev_prev = current->next;
         i++;
       }

   }

 cout<<i<<" three pairs of identical node found\n"l;

}
```

Comment: Is it an assignment requirement that you have your own list implementation, or can you use standard containers?

Comment: And can your problem be more generalized, for example to "remove consecutive duplicates"?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can only use linked list. and to answer your second question, like I explained in my example nodes can only be removed only if they are identical  in a row.        thanks

Comment: Should they also be removed when there are 2 or only when there are 3 in a row?

Comment: Removing consecutive duplicate (identical) values from a linked list is *easy*. Your specific case (remove three nodes if they are identical) is not as easy.

Comment: @Dimfred only when there are 3 in a row. let's there are 4 in a row then the first 3 will be removed.

Comment: One way to solve your specific problem is to use a *sliding window* technique. Always look at the next three nodes (your "window"). The naive implementation would look at "next", "next next" and "next next next".

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking forward in the list rather than looking backwards, for example (I'm sure this can be optimized, I'll leave that as an exercise for you):

```cpp
void Remove_ThreeDuplicates()
{
    Node *current = head;
    Node **prev = &head;
    int found = 0;

    while (current)
    {
        Node *next1 = current->next;
        if (!next1) break;

        Node *next2 = next1->next;
        if (!next2) break;

        if (next1->data == current->data && next2->data == current->data)
        {
            Node *next3 = next2->next;
            *prev = next3;
            delete current;
            delete next1;
            delete next2;
            current = next3;
            ++found;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = &(current->next);
            current = next1;
        }
    }

    cout << found << " triplet of identical nodes found\n";
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/CRrbjU)